# Jquery tmpl and Google SEO

Tags: jquery, templates, seo, rendering

I've got just one question:
Will the google bot find, and get the data from my page if i make it with jQuery.tmpl only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal view on this is that spiders do not run scripts on your site.

This in my view is the best approach to take as although some of Googles' spiders will execute JS it wont always execute all of it or in the way you might be expecting

To view your page exactly how it will be seen by the Google bot set-up a web masters account and user the "fetch as Google bot" option.

But remember although Google is the biggest it is not the only search engine and so I would always recommend not having any content that you want spidered run via JS.

Comment: Just a point of interest Google has recently said that text hidden by JS will be excluded from the indexing of a page.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  It's not going to try interpreting any of the scripts on your page.  And even if it did read through just the html template part, the result wouldn't be very meaningful without merging it first!

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike it's unclear whether googlebot is interpreting scripts or using pattern recognition to pull links out of scripts.  there's an enormous difference between the two.  regardless, for proper SEO, you can't expect google (or whichever other crawler) to merge your jquery templates for you.

Comment: Ok, so I did a search myself.  Although the full article is conspicuously lacking details (which Google will likely never full provide), the source is pretty reputable:  http://blogs.forbes.com/velocity/2010/06/25/google-isnt-just-reading-your-links-its-now-running-your-code/

Comment: If you look at how many times they use the word "some" and "part", you can see that they're not going to just load up a javascript engine and run all your scripts. Furthermore, the functionality described in the article describes would be possible by writing a very intelligent script parser. And as the information applies to this question, there's absolutely no basis to say that they're going to be able to do anything useful with regards to jquery-ui templates.

Comment: Google will not discuss how much javascript is parsed publicly.  I really can't say much more.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes.  Googlebot (in addition to their stealth crawlers) do understand script at some level.

It has been suspected in the community for several years that it did, but they confirmed it a few months ago.  I'm sure you'll find references if you google 'googlebot javascript', but your search would be as good as mine.